# Converting string into array of int c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int

I want to convert the string `str = "12 13 15 20"` into array of integers like `int str_int[4]{12,13,15,20}` using c++.

Comment: What do you have already?

Comment: Create a `stringstream` from it and `while (stream >> val)` push it back on a `vector`. `-1` for lack of effort.

Comment: -1 (and close vote) for lack of effort. Consider doing a search on stack overflow.

Comment: @utnapistim Doesn't matter, he still got answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string s = "12 13 15 20";
    std::stringstream ss( s);

    int i;
    std::vector<int> v;

    while( ss >> i)
        v.push_back( i);

    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                             std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, ","));
    return 0;
}
```

Another option is:

```
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int>( ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(),     
                                                   std::back_inserter(v));
```

Comment: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(is), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(v));` would also work instead of the `while`...

Comment: yes, but this way is faster

Comment: [[citation needed]] :D